# GPS nmea output, saving only last record to external file linux

Tags: 12.04, redirect, gps, tee

I'm using a globalsat G-STAR IV GPS for my Vehicular Ad Hoc networks project. In this, the nmea output coming from the GPS gets updated every 1 second. I want to know if there is a way to save just the last line in an external file and keep overwriting the line in that external file, as and when the GPS sends data signals..

The nmea output sample from my GPS is as follows.

```
$GPGSV,3,1,10,21,55,052,18,22,54,297,13,18,53,011,22,15,18,042,18*75
$GPGSV,3,2,10,14,43,184,,27,33,314,,29,21,152,,16,17,263,*7D
$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,10,092,,19,06,322,*79
$GPRMC,095827.000,A,2335.2440,N,05809.8432,E,0.55,103.38,091114,,,A*66
$GPGGA,095828.000,2335.2443,N,05809.8433,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*46
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095828.000,A,2335.2443,N,05809.8433,E,1.21,102.44,091114,,,A*63
$GPGGA,095829.000,2335.2446,N,05809.8434,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*45
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095829.000,A,2335.2446,N,05809.8434,E,0.92,102.44,091114,,,A*69
$GPGGA,095830.000,2335.2448,N,05809.8437,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*40
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095830.000,A,2335.2448,N,05809.8437,E,1.25,102.12,091114,,,A*62
$GPGGA,095831.000,2335.2450,N,05809.8441,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*49
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095831.000,A,2335.2450,N,05809.8441,E,1.47,101.80,091114,,,A*67
$GPGGA,095832.000,2335.2455,N,05809.8446,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*48
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPGSV,3,1,10,21,55,052,18,22,54,297,14,18,53,011,22,15,18,042,18*72
$GPGSV,3,2,10,14,43,184,,27,33,314,,29,21,152,,16,17,263,*7D
$GPGSV,3,3,10,24,10,092,,19,06,322,*79
$GPRMC,095832.000,A,2335.2455,N,05809.8446,E,2.36,100.07,091114,,,A*6D
$GPGGA,095833.000,2335.2459,N,05809.8450,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*42
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095833.000,A,2335.2459,N,05809.8450,E,1.98,98.52,091114,,,A*50
$GPGGA,095834.000,2335.2458,N,05809.8454,E,1,04,5.2,89.5,M,-34.7,M,,0000*40
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
$GPRMC,095834.000,A,2335.2458,N,05809.8454,E,1.19,98.50,091114,,,A*59
$GPGGA,095835.000,2335.2450,N,05809.8457,E,1,04,5.2,89.6,M,-34.7,M,,0000*49
$GPGSA,A,3,21,22,18,15,,,,,,,,,6.4,5.2,3.6*3C
```

I'm currently saving this output to an external file through the terminal in linux command:

```
ima@ubuntu12:~$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tee gpsoutput.tr
```

i have also tried `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tee >(tail -n 1 > gpsout.tr)` but it does not update dynamically.

But , i need a way to save just the last line coming from the GPS into that external file. that is,, it keeps overwriting the file and replaces with the most recent line coming from GPS.
Please help..
thank You

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
watch -n 1 "tail -n 1 /dev/ttyUSB0 > gpsout.tr"
```